# MD5 each file in a folder and also MD5 the folder

Tags: c#, hash, md5

If I could please ask for some assistance with a problem I have, I'd like to open a folder display each file and its hash and then at the end of the displayed files I'd like a hash to display of the total folder structure. The code below isn't correct as it adds the path MD5 to the file MD5.

The code below displays each file in a listbox and under that a hash but the hash code is the hash for the folder just repeated for each file.

```
private void btnFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            txtFolder.Text = _path;
            // assuming you want to include nested folders
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(_path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                 .OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
            foreach (string items in files)
            {
                MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    string file = files[i];
                    // hash path
                    string relativePath = file.Substring(_path.Length + 1);
                    byte[] pathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(relativePath.ToLower());
                    md5.TransformBlock(pathBytes, 0, pathBytes.Length, pathBytes, 0);

                    // hash contents
                    byte[] contentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
                    if (i == files.Count - 1)
                        md5.TransformFinalBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
                    else
                        md5.TransformBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length, contentBytes, 0);
                }
                lstBox.Items.Add(items);
                lstBox.Items.Add(BitConverter.ToString(md5.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Why are you looping through your `files` array twice? (Once with `foreach` and again with `for int i`. That would be why you are getting a total hash each time, since you are hashing all files each time

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that will output your desired output and requirements.
Please read the *"NOTE"* sections in the code for more information.

You **should not** run this in your *UI thread* since it will lock it down until all files have been processed. Please look at **refactoring** your method into something that you can called in a thread.

```
private void btnFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
  if (result == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    _path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    txtInput.Text = _path;
    // assuming you want to include nested folders
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(_path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                          .OrderBy(p => p).ToList();

    MD5 totalMD5 = MD5.Create();
    int bytesToReadAtOnce = 2048; // NOTE: This can be changed to bigger or smaller.

    foreach (string singleFile in files)
    {
      MD5 singleMD5 = MD5.Create();

      // hash contents
      // NOTE: This is nice for small files, but a memory eater for big files
      //byte[] contentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(singleFile);
      //singleMD5.TransformFinalBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);

      using (FileStream inputFile = File.OpenRead(singleFile))
      {
        byte[] content = new byte[bytesToReadAtOnce];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        // Read the file only in chunks, allowing minimal memory usage.
        while ((bytesRead = inputFile.Read(content, 0, bytesToReadAtOnce)) > 0)
        {
          totalMD5.TransformBlock(content, 0, bytesRead, content, 0);
          singleMD5.TransformBlock(content, 0, bytesRead, content, 0);
        }

        // Close the singleMD5 block with 0 length
        singleMD5.TransformFinalBlock(content, 0, 0);

        // Output per file
        lstBox.Items.Add(string.Format("File: {0}", singleFile));
        lstBox.Items.Add(string.Format("MD5 : {0}", BitConverter.ToString(singleMD5.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToUpper()));
      }
    }

    // Close the totalMD5 with an empty byte[] and 0 length (basically does nothing but close the Block)
    totalMD5.TransformFinalBlock(new byte[0], 0, 0);

    // Output for total
    lstBox.Items.Insert(0, Environment.NewLine);
    lstBox.Items.Insert(0, string.Format("Total MD5 : {0}", BitConverter.ToString(totalMD5.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToUpper()));
    lstBox.Items.Insert(0, string.Format("Root Path : {0}", _path));
  }
  else
  {
    return;
  }
}
```

With the change to read each file only in chunks, I *accidentally* let this code run on a folder with 287k Files in it, totalling ~41GB size.
The memory usage didn't go above 7MB during the entire processing of the directory.

Comment: Your solution works except for some reason the MD5 hash doesn't match a Python MD5 script I have and nor does the hash match the one produced by the Microsoft File Integrity Verifier... fciv.exe The Python script and the fciv both give the same result on files.

Comment: @Exception Are you including the bytes of the path string of each file into the generated hash in the Python and MFIV? If you remove the part that adds the bytes of the path to the MD5, the hashes should match.

Comment: Sorry mate, I've been commenting out everything and changing things around for an hour and still can't get it to work, If I comment out the part where you state your adding the path to the end of the hash I get an exception stating the hash must be finalized before the hash value is retrieved.

Comment: @Exception Adding of the path's bytes to the MD5 was according to your original code, if that wasn't intended then I can modify the code to not do that

Comment: The way you have set it up to display in the listbox is what I'm after i.e. Showing the MD5 of the whole folder and then showing each file in it with each files MD5 without the file paths MD5 added to the files. I'll edit the original post description. I think this is a good solution that others would like. I will be reading files in the hundreds of GB's and your solution is nice with the bytes to read option.

Comment: If the bytes are still not matching up with python there are a few things that could cause it. 1) If all the files are wrong it could be that Python is not using UTF8 to get the byte arrays for the file paths 2) If the files are correct but the total is wrong Python could be processing the files in a different order, this would cause the total hash to be calculated in a different way.

Comment: @Exception, code updated to exclude the Path from the MD5 checksum. MD5 generated now matched the MD5's from MS Integrity checker and http://onlinemd5.com/.

Comment: @Bernd that did the trick! Thanks, now to just implement a back ground worker or the like to handle the freezing.